# Generate Custom Specflow Feature File Template

Tags: bdd, specflow

Our team uses feature files that need to be decorated with certain tags and follows certain Scenario and Feature Naming convention.

Is is possible to generate a customized template specific to my team such that when the user adds a new feature file using 'Add Item' of Visual Studio, the customized template shows up instead of the regular template

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own file and project templates which contain whatever you want.

See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx) for details of how to do that

Comment: This works for new standard code files you then edit however specflow system generate .cs code from the .feature file each time they are modified so this is after you create a new file. A specflow plugin is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible however you will need to create a specflow plugin then update your specflow config to use this new dll.

The plugin is triggered each time the files are generated.

Full documentation can be found here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Plugins

Comment: I think the op wanted a way to generate standardised feature files, not change what is generated in the feature.cs file